# API returned an error: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to integrate monnify payment gateway in a project, everything works fine when using the sandbox base_url (https://sandbox.monnify.com/api) but cease to work with production base_url (https://api.monnify.com) with live keys.

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => config("settings.monnify_url")."/v1/auth/login",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode(config("settings.monnify_key").":".config("settings.monnify_secret")), 
        ],
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    if($err) {
        die("Culr returned an error: " .$err);
    }

    return $response;
```

Comment: Have you checked the key you got is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You must encode the semicolon `:` also:

`$header = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password);`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had omitted `/api` in the base_url.

I initially used:

> https://api.monnify.com/v1/auth/login

instead of:

> https://api.monnify.com/api/v1/auth/login